# Modal Box - Show only the inside of the box

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I'm trying to do a modal box, where it only shows the "inside".

Right now I'm seeing this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7W8S.png)

But I would like to see this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzDw2.png)

Code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Text1................................</p>
        <p>Text2................................</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="float:right;">
        <button class="next-button"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .close {
        display:none;
    }

    .next-button:active {
        outline: none;
        border: none;
    }

    .next-button:focus {
        outline: none;
        border: none;
    }

    .next-button:after {
        outline: none;
        border: none;
    }
</style>
```

So, I would like to remove everything outside of the thin gray border - the white space and cross.
Can anyone show me, how this is achieved? Thank you

**EDIT:**
I went for another solution, that didn't javascript, made it much more simple:
https://gist.github.com/conficient/ba98d1662c659e170ec16650acea05c8

Comment: Please share our css code

Comment: @Andrew Sure, but it contains next to nothing. I've updated the question

Comment: You are using bootstrap, right?

Comment: @kalgoritmi yes, I am

Comment: Share your code

Comment: I just update answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand u want something like that:

[image]
Example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/zovguawh/77/)

Code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Text1................................</p>
        <p>Text2................................</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="float:right;">
        <button class="next-button"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPD:**

CSS:

```
.next-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
}
```

Or for hiding **X** u can provide next code:

```
.modal-header .btn-close {
 display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how I would like it to look like. But somehow, it looks like this for me, even though I nearly copy pasted your solution: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrlOL.png)

Comment: @Palle try to use new version Bootstrap, in jsfiddle in resoures u can see all links which i use

Comment: @Palle and try Ctrl+F5, in some reason it's can help

Comment: I update the bootstrap from the jsfiddle you posted, and used ctrl + f5, but unfortunately that didn't do the trick for me

Comment: @Palle than please create JSfiddle with your code, i will check whats wrong.

Comment: Ok, so it works for me in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ysnbeour/1/

Comment: So it must be a problem with the bootstrap linking?

Comment: @Palle please inspect your code, and maybe you have some issues with cusstom classes or bootstrap css

Comment: I can't seem to find any problems... I'll put it aside and look at it again tomorrow. Thanks for your help anyway @Andrew

Comment: What I notices is that, it displays correctly, when I remove the "modal fade" div. I've looked for any mistake for quite some time now, but I just can't seem to find anything wrong..